# PHP include incorrect search path taken?

Tags: php, include, php-internals

I have a file `test.php` in the folder `myfolder`. `myfolder` also contains another folder called `inner`.

Both `myfolder` and `inner` contain a file called msg.php. The entire layout looks like this:

- myfolder

  - test.php
  - inner

    - msg.php
  - msg.php

In `test.php`, I've set the include_path to `./inner` and included the file `msg.php`:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("include_path", "./inner");
echo ini_get('include_path'); // shows ./inner
include("msg.php"); // outputs hello from myfolder/inner/msg.php
?>
```

However, if I modify the working directory to `./inner`, `myfolder/msg.php` will be included instead of `myfolder/inner/msg.php`:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("include_path", "./inner");
echo ini_get('include_path'); // shows ./inner
chdir('./inner');
include("msg.php"); // outputs hello from myfolder/msg.php
?>
```

Shouldn't the second piece of code include `myfolder/inner/msg.php` instead of `myfolder/msg.php`?

Comment: side note.. your overwriting your include path completely when you do `ini_set("include_path", "./inner");` always be sure to also include the current include path when adding a new include path

Comment: @DevZer0, yes I am overwriting the include path. Thus the second piece of code should include myfolder/inner/msg.php instead of myfolder/msg.php right?

Comment: In the second example, you chdir to `./inner` then tell it to set the `include_path` to a dir `./inner` which doesn't exist. You're actually telling it to set the include dir to `/inner/inner`. Try setting the include dir to `/inner` instead of `./inner`

Comment: yes it should include `./inner`

Comment: Since the include_path in your 2nd example doesn't exist the include will trigger this behavior: "If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing."

Comment: @Akam, see the changes.

Comment: @Pacerier: No, it checks in the script's calling dir first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first take a look at your directory path syntax.

```
./inner
```

This is saying, look in the current directory (`./`) for a directory called `inner`.

Before you set the `include_path` to `./inner`, though, you change the current working directory to `./inner`, so now you are effectively looking for `/myfolder/inner/inner/msg.php`.

Let's take a look at your code again.

```
//Current working directory is /myfolder

//Here you change the current working directory to /myfolder/inner
chdir('./inner');

//Here you set the include_path to the directory inner in the current working directory, or /myfolder/inner/inner
ini_set("include_path", "./inner");

//You echo out the explicit value of include_path, which, of course, is ./inner
echo ini_get('include_path'); // shows ./inner

//include fails to find msg.php in /myfolder/inner/inner so it looks in the scripts directory, which is /myfolder/msg.php.
include("msg.php"); // outputs hello from myfolder/msg.php
```

Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) which states the following about what happens if `include()` can't find the file referenced in the provided path:

> include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and
>   the current working directory before failing.

You should try setting the include_path to `/myfolder/inner` or, if `/myfolder` is actually your root, then you could just set it to `/inner`. Notice the omission of the `.` which means `current working directory`. Just using a `/` means look in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your path is wrong, take of the "./" from the path. From what I see it look like you are coming out of the myfolder and then looking for a inner outwith it.

Check the docs for the include function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

> include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing

Comment: The quote in your answer is why it still finds `/myfolder/msg.php` after failing to find `/myfolder/inner/inner/msg.php`